# How can I define a new operator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, operators

I'm trying to define an operator `=>>` that checks if one of its operands is double of the other operand.

I tried so far:

```
:- op(200, xfy, =>>).

=>>(L, R) :- double(L, R); double(R, L). 

double(L, R) :- L is R * 2.
```

But when used in RPEL, I got :

```
?- (-8) =>> (-4).
true ;
false. 
%^^^^ note here

?- 7 =>> 3.
false.

?- 40 =>> 20.
true ;
false.
%^^^^ note here

?- 20 =>> 40.
true.
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: I wonder you mean with RPEL: REPL (read-eval-print-loop)? There's also the tag [tag:prolog-toplevel] for that...

Comment: declaratively, the read-print-eval-loop (RPEL) is just a synonym of the read-eval-print-loop (REPL), as is the print-eval-read-loop  (PERL) ;-)

Comment: Defining your own operator for such a secondary predicate is definitely not a good idea. And if you would, you should at least use the same priority and (non-) associativity as `=`. That is `op(700, xfx, =)`. And since your relation is symmetric, use also a name that reflects this, like `=><=` or whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a determinism issue: There may be further solutions (`(;)/2` can be read as "*or*"), and therefore Prolog backtracks (and finds no alternative).

There is an easy way to fix this: Use `once/1` to commit to the first solution, if any:

```
L =>> R :- once((double(L, R) ; double(R, L))).
```

Notice also that you may want to use `=:=/2`, not `is/2`, in this case. Even better, if you are working over integers, simply use CLP(FD) constraints, and your predicate will be deterministic *and* much more general:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

L =>> R :- L #= R*2 #\/ R #= L*2.
```

Examples:

```
?- 40 =>> 20.
true.

?- 40 =>> X, X #< 80.
X = 20.

?- X =>> Y, X #= 2, Y #= 3.
false.
```

Comment: Is this really the strongest formulation? I rather thought that one would need `abs/1` or `min/2` for it.

Comment: `*` (times) can propagate quite nicely if one argument is already known.

Comment: BTW: Intended, that `library(clpfd)` lacks `sign/1`?

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues.  First, defining an operator for such a tiny task is a bit of an overkill. Always keep in mind the cost of declaring an operator: Every time you define an operator you change the language a bit which means that people who read that program text will have to learn that syntax as well.

So best would be to just stay with a simple predicate name. And if you really insist on it, try to use operators in a way, similar to existing operators. We have roughly the following three groups  in ISO Prolog according to their priority:

- 1200-900: Rules, control constructs. Most notably conjunction is 1000.
- 700, `xfx`: Comparison related infix operators like: `= \= == \== @< @=< @> @>= =.. is =:= =\= < =< > >=`. Note that these are all non-associative, since nesting is not specific to their meaning.
- 500-200: Expressions.

Also note that all the symmetric relations have symmetric names — except for the negated ones: `\=` and `\==`.

```
:- op(700,xfx,=:*:=).

=:*:=(X, Y) :-
   (X - 2*Y) * (Y - 2*X) =:= 0.
```

The following might be preferable since the intermediary results are smaller and thus multiplication is cheaper and never produces an overflow:

```
=:*:=(X, Y) :-
   sign(X - 2*Y) * sign(Y - 2*X) =:= 0.
```